# ByteBuddy create class from created class

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have an `interface` with some methods (unknown count).

I want to create another `interface` with methods, which will have same name and parameter types, but not return types.

Then, I want use second created `interface` for create a new `class` by `byteBuddy`. But when I use the created `interface` for creating a new one, I get

> IllegalStateException: Could not locate class file for
>   SecondInterface.

example code:

```
Class<?> clazz
= new ByteBuddy()
    .makeInterface()
    .name("secondInterface")
    .make()
    .load(classLoader)
    .getLoaded();

for (Method method : FirstInterface.class.getMethods()) {

    Class<?>[] classes = method.getParameterTypes();
    List<Class<?>> classList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(classes));
    classList.add(Object.class);

    clazz
    = new ByteBuddy()
        .rebase(clazz)
        .defineMethod(method.getName() + "Reverse", Void.class, Modifier.PUBLIC)
        .withParameters(classList)
        .withoutCode()
        .make()
        .load(classLoader)
        .getLoaded();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is byteBuddy allowed to create a class from a another which was just created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rebasing a class, you are editing its already existing class file where all existing methods are retained. Is this really what you are trying to do here? I'd rather define a new interface and add the methods to it, then you will neither run into the exception.

The reason you are seeing this error is that you are loading the interface using a class loader that does not retain the original byte code as a resource what is required for future editing. Provide `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER_PERSISTENT` as a second argument to `load` and you will get around it.