# ByteBuddy how to create a subclass of another ByteBuddy created Class in Android?

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy

I am writing a java code for android using `byte-buddy:1.10.17` and `byte-buddy-android:1.10.17` to dynamically create classes. I want to dynamically create a class which would be sub class of another dynamically created class.
Here is a sample code of what I want to do

```
AndroidClassLoadingStrategy loadingStrategy = new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Wrapping(context.getCacheDir());

DynamicType.Builder builder = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).name("TestParentClass");

Class testParentClass = builder.make().load(Test.class.getClassLoader(), loadingStrategy).getLoaded();

builder = new ByteBuddy().subclass(testParentClass).name("TestChildClass");

Class testChildClass = builder.make().load(Test.class.getClassLoader(), loadingStrategy).getLoaded();
```

but I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "TestParentClass"` when creating the child class.

I also have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287446/bytebuddy-create-class-from-created-class) but it did not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the class-loader of Test.  That will be looking for a class file in your classpath.  There will be none for the dynamic class TestParentClass.  Instead, get the class-loader from TestParentClass:

```
Class testChildClass = builder.make().load(testParentClass.getClassLoader(), loadingStrategy).getLoaded();
```